# How to enable Save and SaveAs actions for an editor which extends FormEditor class

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have an editor class which extends FormEditor class. In order to achieve `save` and `save As` functionality for this editor, will it be enough to override:

1. doSave(IProgressMonitor monitor)
2. doSaveAs()
3. isSaveAsAllowed()

these methods alone? Or anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Please consider also the following

- Your editor must be dirty, that means you must have called `firePropertyChange(PROP_DIRTY)` before
- If you build your own RCP make sure you have added `Save` and `Save As...` Menu-Items in your `ActionBarAdvisor`
- consider using the doSave Methods of the integrated FormPages (this makes sometimes more sense)
- Do not integrate any custom user-interaction (e.g. additional dialogs) in doSave or doSaveAs methods.
- consider providing a command-stack that the user can undo/redo modifications regarding the editors input
- make sure to handle the fact that your editor-input can be changed in the meantime (e.g. if another editor manpulates the editors input).

Comment: Where should this firePropertyChange(PROP_DIRTY) be called?

Comment: Every time the user edits something (the editor has to show this '*' in its title)

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent post on the Eclipse Community Forums about this: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/140214/

An extract:

> You are using an instance of FormEditor as your editor. This editor 
>   contains instances of FormPage as pages. I hope that you have 
>   specialized SectionParts (or AbstractParts) as sections in the page.
>   In  the section you have Text widgets that display some data and have
>   an  ModifyListener attached. In this listener call markDirty() for the
>   section and the ManagedForm and FormEditor will handle dirty state for
>   you. And don't forget to add each SectionPart to the ManagedForm by 
>   addPart(section)!

So essentially all you need is:

```
public class MyPage extends FormPage implements ModifyListener {

    private SectionPart secPart;
    private Text myText;

    public MyPage(FormEditor editor, String id, String title) {
        super(editor, id, title);
    }

    @Override
    protected void createFormContent(IManagedForm form) {

        secPart = new SectionPart(formBody, toolkit, Section.DESCRIPTION
                | Section.TITLE_BAR);
        Section section = secPart.getSection();

        //add labels and controls for the three fields
        myText = new Text(composite, SWT.BORDER);
        myText.addModifyListener(this);

        form.addPart(secPart);
    }

    public void modifyText(ModifyEvent arg0) {
        secPart.markDirty();
    }
}
```

As a side note, editorDirtyStateChanged() from FormEditor will nudge your plugin after you have made a save - to make the pages follow suit use commitPages(true). These methods are to be used AFTER you have saved of course - to let your workbench know everything is clean again.